# How to accelerate data access in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database on an android device with the following scheme:

```
    create table 'main' ('_id' integer primary key, 'word' text unique not null);
```

The number of rows won't change in the future and currently is 600000.

Since performance (speed) is very important in the app, I want to find a way to speed up the following two queries which are used very frequently in the app:

```
    select * from [main] where '_id'=...
    select * from [main] where 'word'=...
```

So far, I've been told to uses indexes, or bulk transactions. but I don't know how to utilize these two approaches and how far I can expect them to improve the performance. By the way, do you know of any other tips?

Comment: I suggest that you do some research to learn more about indexes and bulk transactions. These are commonly used in most databases, not just SQLite.

Comment: p.s. `primary key` automatically creates an index, so selecting on the `_id` field should be relatively efficient.

Comment: #Code-Guru: Thank you. I wanna know if creating indexes _which occurs by default if a column has 'unique' restriction_ is the only possible way of accelerating data access in DMSes?

Comment: [Read](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) [the](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

Comment: If you just select the columns you really need, instead of ALL (*), some speed up will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` to see how much work the database engine has to do to satisfy your queries: whether a full table scan is needed or the query can be satisfied quickly with an index.

Both `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints will automatically create an index so you don't need to create indices for these columns yourself.

In your `SELECT`s, remove the `''` quotes from your column names - they will be treated as literals and not column names.

Example:

```
sqlite> create table 'main' ('_id' integer primary key, 'word' text unique not null);
sqlite> explain query plan select * from [main] where '_id'='...';
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE main (~1000000 rows)
sqlite> explain query plan select * from [main] where _id='...';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE main USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
sqlite> explain query plan select * from [main] where 'word'='...';
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE main (~1000000 rows)
sqlite> explain query plan select * from [main] where word='...';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE main USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_main_1 (word=?) (~1 rows)
```